# Codeigniter PDO emulate prepare

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pdo, prepared-statement

I have been reading around and people say that when setting up your connection with your Database that you should add

```
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

Telling PDO to disable emulated prepared statements using real PDO statements.

How do I set up this up in Codeigniter?

I am using codeigniter 2.1.3

Edit 1:

How I connect now :

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = FALSE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'mysql:host=localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'XXXXXXX';
$db['default']['password'] = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
$db['default']['database'] = 'XXXXXXX';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

and a query example is :

```
function validate_login()
    {
    $bcrypt = new Bcrypt(17);   
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :user";
    $loginQ = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql);
    $loginQ->bindParam(':user', $this->input->post('username'));
    $loginQ->execute(); 
    $row = $loginQ->fetch();
    $hash = $row['password'];
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $verified = $bcrypt->verify($password, $hash);

        if($bcrypt->verify($password, $hash))
        {
            return $loginQ;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

system/database/drivers/pdo around line 96 you can edit the error mode and you can add emulate prepares to false. Now most db servers can take advantage of this, I know mysql does. hopefully this helps any one else.

```
function db_connect()
    {
        $this->options['PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE'] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
        $this->options['PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES'] = FALSE;

        return new PDO($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->options);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled quite a while with this one. And I was unable to find a working solution that wasn't too hacky. This is what I came up with. Works inside all controllers, but can be extended to any CI classes in the similar way.

1. Change **application/config/database.php** to use PDO:

   ```
   $db['default'] = array(
       'dsn'   => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname={{my_db}};charset=utf8;',
       'username' => 'my_db_user',
       'password' => '123',
       'database' => 'my_db',
       'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
       ...
   );
   ```
2. Create MY_Controller class to extend CI_Controller **application/core/MY_Controller.php**:

   ```
   class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
       public function __construct() {
           parent::__construct();
           $this->db->conn_id->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Using the extended class in controllers. Change this in all of your controllers (Example Users controller):

Change this:

class Users extends **CI**_Controller {

into this ->

class Users extends **MY**_Controller {

Now you should have all the data returned from the DB with correct types. Tested on CI3, but I believe it should also work on CI2.